# How to avoid receiving duplicate request in controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I have build WebApi service(MvcApplication) that recive UserName ,and Email.

i have url to this service:

```
Ex: www.domain.com/Controller/SendUser
```

And i have some affiliates  that use this URL to my service  in they website/landing page,and they send me data with Username,and Email of potential client.

Some affiliates  have build they submit form wrong,and allow to  users press SEND button many times before they see response on the screen or redirect to next page.And here where the problem appears.

I getting 5-10 request to my service with duplicate data,and start to run all my validation function and methods insert to database.

**IMPORTANT**:
I don't wont solution on **database** level,i want to stop the request in the beginning,don't even start all validation services.

I need to receive  request,temporary save UserName+Email,and if i receiving in the same second or in next 10 seconds the same  UserName+Email just to avoid it.

I tries to add static dictionary to Global.asax and save EncodedLead(from User+Email),I lock the my dictionary GlobalMemoryLeads before i check if ContainsKey(X),and than i add a key,but some how i still get error that key is all ready exist even when dictionary is lock.

It seems that threads go throw lock and try to add the same key even when
GlobalMemoryLeads.ContainsKey(EncodedLead) return false,sow another thread can add key to dictionary that is locked by another thread??What i am missing here?

How to avoid duplicate requests?

> UPDATED

My code:

```
      [AcceptVerbs(WebRequestMethods.Http.Get, WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)]
      [AllowCrossSiteJson]
        public ActionResult SendUser(string UserName, string Email, )
        {
          string response = "";
          bool duplicate=false;
          try
           { 
          string Lead = UserName + email;
          int  EncodedLead = Lead.GetHashCode();

           //here i lock my GlobalMemoryLeads dictionary
        lock (MvcApplication.GlobalMemoryLeads)
           {
            //here i check if that key is all ready ContainsKey
       if (!MvcApplication.GlobalMemoryLeads.ContainsKey(EncodedLead))
           {
              try
              {
                MvcApplication.GlobalMemoryLeads.Add(EncodedLead, false);
              }
         catch (Exception ex)
       {

   //here i get error that key is all ready exist
   //how it possible if i have 
   //1: Globalizes lock
   //2 i check ContainsKey before
    return Json(new { respondNotSuccess = "Duplicate Lead" });
     }

            }

               }

             }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response = "Exception " + ex.Message;

            }

            return Json(new { respondSuccess = response });
        }
```

Comment: is `GlobalMemoryLeads` a `Dictionary` or is it a `ConcurrentDictionary`?  If it is a `Dictionary` that is not safe to call on multiple threads. Also, have you considered using a actual [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a dictionary, you get some added benefits like sliding expiration windows.

Comment: Could you change the submitting form to disable the button on first submit?

Comment: mjwills,no.My affiliates have they own forms that use only my URl to send data,i dont' have access to they code/form

Comment: Did you know that your asp.net solution can run in multiple processes? There is no guarantee that each request from a affiliate site will be handled by the same process. So a global dictionary is not global for asp.net

Comment: You need to verify duplicates against the database. That is the best way to do this. The data layer is stateful. WebApi & Rest in general should be stateless. You are trying to create state in your WebApi layer. Either you or the colleauge who has to maintain this will regret it if you are successful.

Comment: Sir Rufo: No i didn't know it,You mean if i have receive 3 request in the same time it can run 3 process and each one with they own one thread ?And it will build 3  dictionary in Global.asax?

Comment: @VovaPotapov Think about it as if you start an application multiple times. They are not aware about anything inside the other application processes

Comment: @ Sir Rufo - i don't understand , if there is 2 processes that mean they have 2 GlobalMemoryLeads(dictionary) right?And there is no problem to add the same key to 2 different dictionary. Sow how it possible that my dictionary  is in lock and i add key after i check 'ContainsKey' i still get error that 'key is all ready exist' ?It seems like the threads in the same process  can use my dictionary in the same time even if dictionary is lock.

Comment: @VovaPotapov: Could you check the exception type?

Comment: @Jacod Phan: sorry it took me a while to catch this error again.             sow: Message(An item with the same key has already been added.) and  Type(ArgumentException)

Answer (score 1):

In general, avoid locking on a public type, or instances beyond your code's control.

The common constructs lock (this), lock (typeof (MyType)), and lock ("myLock") violate this guideline:

- lock (this) is a problem if the instance can be accessed publicly.
- lock (typeof (MyType)) is a problem if MyType is publicly accessible.
- lock ("myLock") is a problem because any other code in the process using the same string, will share the same lock.

Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private static object variable to protect data common to all instances

try to do something like that:

```
private Object thisLock = new Object();

lock (thisLock)
   {
      if (!MvcApplication.GlobalMemoryLeads.ContainsKey(EncodedLead))
      {
          try
          {
             MvcApplication.GlobalMemoryLeads.Add(EncodedLead, false);
             ...
```